# Constrained Permutation Problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This isn't homework -- just a problem I came up with to test my skills.  I failed, for now.

> A teacher must arrange $n$ students into a line, but
>       $k$ pairs of the students cannot stand one another and
>       will fight if they are placed next to each other. How
>       many peaceful arrangements of the students are there?

If $k = 1$, we can characterize the admissible sequences as structures of the form

> $$(C_1, \cdots, C_{i-1}, (C_i, (C_{i+1} \cdots C_{j-1}), C_j), \cdots C_n)$$

So that the triple in the sequence corresponds to the necessary arrangement where at least once child is between $C_i$ and $C_j$, the unruly students.

Given any such structure, there are $(2! * (n - 2)!)$ relabelings which preserve the invariant (since we only care that $C_i$ and $C_j$ are apart by some natural number of students)

Now I'm stuck counting the structures.  It appears that it can be solved using an occupancy number model.  There are $a$ students before the unruly triple, $(b+2)$ students in the triple, and $c$ students after the triple, so that $a + (b + 2) + c = n$, where $b \geq 1$.

Can anybody help finish the write up as presented?  I didn't even get past the k=1 case. :(

Is there a slick argument I should learn?  (I'm using these problems to come up with "short cut" flash cards to memorize)

Comment: Instead of trying to directly count the number of arrangements where students stand next to each other, consider counting the number of arrangements where they *do* stand next to each other and subtracting that from the total number of possible arrangements.

Comment: If you're still stuck after Joe's complement hint, use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.